How to construct !Send objects on another thread?
I have the following code:
trait Foo {
  fn do_it(&self) -> ();
}

struct FooImpl {
  make_this_not_send: *const (),
}

impl Foo for FooImpl { ... }

fn spawn(new: impl FnOnce() -> Box<dyn Foo> + Send + 'static) {
  tokio::spawn(async move {
    let foo = new();
    
    loop {
      foo.do_it();

      // ...
    }
  });
}

Problem is that this does not compile because Foo is not easily Send. I do not really understand why it needs to be though. I only want to create a foo in some thread and leave it there. I hoped the new() approach outlined above would do it, but it still requires Foo to be Send.
Why does it need to be Send?
What is the idiomatic way of solving this problem?

tokio tasks can move between threads, so all values kept between .awaits must be Send.

If you don't need async capabilities where you use Foo then use spawn_blocking instead, which spawns a sync thread, not a Tokio task. That should work just fine in this case.

Well I understand the problem. Would it be ill-advised to do a std::thread::spawn and invoke functions there via a std::sync::mpsc::channel or the like? I suppose blocking on the std::sync is not optimal while managed by tokio, but it would solve the problem. (I need to use async/await in the broader context of the spawned loop)

You can have a std::thread which communicates via tokio channels (they have also blocking interfaces) with your async parts. If this is a good idea really depends on your usecase

The default tokio runtime is multi-threaded, so this means that any Future has to be able to be Send to another thread.
This means that any async function which owns an non Send object across .await calls will not be Send and does not work with the multi-threaded runtime.
You have three options:

Restrict the scope of the non Send object between .await calls.
Use the single thread runtime, which does not require the Futures to be Send
Use a blocking thread for this task (see comment by @cdhowie)


To add on this: According to the tokio bridging docs (https://tokio.rs/tokio/topics/bridging) it seems reasonable enough to spawn a std::thread and run a new single threaded runtime in it. This solves the problem as well.
